# Are browser cookies and other headers visible during HTTPS?

Tags: https

When using a HTTPS connection are browser cookies and HTTP headers visible as plain text? That is, is only the body of the HTTP content encrypted?

Comment: possible duplicate of [With HTTPS, are the URL and the request headers protected as the request body is?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8858102/with-https-are-the-url-and-the-request-headers-protected-as-the-request-body-is)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both the request and response are fully encrypted – so the cookies and all headers are protected. About the only thing visible to an external sniffer is the host and remote address (IP) that you're requesting.

Answer (score 1):

All https is http over an encrypted connection i.e. the contents of the TCP/IP packets are encrypted.

Comment: It's not so much the "TCP/IP packets" (which is quite vague), but the application layer that's encrypted.