# How to send data securely as parameters in URL?

Tags: security, http, encryption, ssl, get

As [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2629241/327528) suggests, it isn't a good idea to have sensitive information in a URL string.  Even though it will be encrypted if you use SSL, it will be stored in a server log in clear text.

How then should GET arguments be passed to a web server securely?

Comment: POST parameters aren't in the URL. What's your question?

Comment: Also, querystring will not be encrypted if you use SSL.

Comment: @ChrisBint Please read [Are querystring parameters secure in HTTPS (HTTP + SSL)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2629222/are-querystring-parameters-secure-in-https-http-ssl).

Comment: @bmargulies: my mistake, question edited.

Comment: @ChrisBint, [the query string *will* be encrypted when using HTTPS](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8858241/372643).

Comment: Apologies, what I meant is that although the communication is sent encrypted, the (visible in logs and history) querystring does not get modified (encrypted).

Answer (score 3):

You are confusing GET with POST data. That answer talks about the query string, that is the arguments in the url, which are passed by GET, you shouldn't pass sensitive data on them, instead pass it in [POST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_%28HTTP%29) fields and [Http-Headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561381/custom-http-headers-naming-conventions).

Comment: [Post](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_(HTTP)) and [Http-Headers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561381/custom-http-headers-naming-conventions) are the recommended way to to send data through SSL/TLS Securely.

Comment: @ErikPhilips I've edited my answer to complete with your http-headers suggestion and make some links. thanks! :-)