# How to use 'implicit' grant type with spring + oauth2

Tags: spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

How i can make a request with implicit grant type ?.  i have googled it and couldn't found any example for it.

All i  want is to use implicit grant type in my HTML5 app but i am not sure how i can configure it , i am able to use other grant types.

Thanks

Comment: do u know how to configure a different grant type (e.g. Authorization Code)? does [this link](http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-23) help?

Comment: and this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14297805/oauth-2-0-implicit-grant-security

Comment: I am using Spring Security + oAuth2 and if i make request with grant_type=implict than server returns {
error: "invalid_grant"
error_description: "Implicit grant type not supported from token endpoint"
}

Comment: If i check code of oAuth2 here https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/master/spring-security-oauth2/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/endpoint/TokenEndpoint.java it throws exception as given in TokenEndpoint.java if (tokenRequest.getGrantType().equals("implicit")) {
   throw new InvalidGrantException("Implicit grant type not supported from token endpoint");
  }

Comment: im sure @DaveSayer will soon come up with the answer :-)

Comment: Did you read the spec? An implicit grant comes from the authorize endpoint.

Comment: I will get back to you after reading spec again. Thanks for your help

Comment: Have you been able to make this work? If so, can you post your solution?