# Are URL segments protected in HTTPS (SSL) request?

Tags: url, ssl, https, get

We are accessing an API where the data is being sent in URL segments as a JSON string:

```
https://uri.to/api/endpoint/{"key":"value"}
```

Is the data in the JSON url segment actually protected/encrypted as part of the HTTPS transaction?

I am aware that *querystrings* are protected, but this is **not** a querystring, rather a URL segment.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [With HTTPS, are the URL and the request headers protected as the request body is?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8858102/with-https-are-the-url-and-the-request-headers-protected-as-the-request-body-is)