# How to get digital signature of the request (in two-way SSL)?

Tags: asp.net, ssl, httprequest, client-certificates

In an ASP.Net web app, which runs on HTTPS and has RequireClientCertificate set in web.config, I need to receive the client certificate of the user and digital signature of the request on the server. The certificate is found in HttpContext.Request.ClientCertificate, but I can't find the signed data. The post params are automatically decoded and decrypted, but I need the signature too. Does anyone know where is it found or is it possible to get it?

One more question, when the browser asks for your certificate and hands it to the server, does it encrypt the whole HttpRequest with your private key or just a part of it (for example post params)?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> One more question, when the browser asks for your certificate and
>   hands it to the server, does it encrypt the whole HttpRequest with
>   your private key or just a part of it (for example post params)?

Firstly, it doesn't make sense to "encrypt with a private key": you *sign* with a private key. While some algorithms (e.g. RSA) use very similar procedures to encrypt and sign, "encrypt" means "hiding" something: you're not hiding anything if anyone with the public key can decipher it.

Secondly, SSL/TLS uses symmetric keys (negotiated during the handshake) for encryption, not the keys in the certificates. The [whole HTTP request will indeed be encrypted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8858241/372643) in this case.

> The certificate is found in HttpContext.Request.ClientCertificate, but
>   I can't find the signed data. The post params are automatically
>   decoded and decrypted, but I need the signature too. Does anyone know
>   where is it found or is it possible to get it?

What's signed when using a client certificate is the handshake messages, not the HTTP request. Once the appropriate verification has been made by your SSL/TLS stack, it's unlikely to be of any use, either technically or [administratively](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/41777/2435). (This is why it is generally not accessible.)

Comment: Thanks for the useful information! Now, is it possible to manually (via ASP.Net) request a client certificate to sign my challenge?