# UrlReferrer from https domain to other domain

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, url, redirect

I know `https` doesn't send `UrlReferrer` for security reasons. But is there any way how can I get the `UrlReferrer`. I am testing a web app and need to send `UrlReferrer` to 2nd domain.

If I use a middle domain just for redirection then it's sending `UrlReferrer = null`, is there any way to set custom `UrlReferrer` when redirecting from middle domain to other domain in asp.net MVC?

or is there any way to preserve `UrlReferrer` from https, we don't want to use something in URL, because we don't want to show user we are checking it. we don't wanna serve the page of 2nd domain if use came there direct not from first domain.

Any suggestions, please.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [URLReferrer is null when page is HTTPS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8848774/urlreferrer-is-null-when-page-is-https)

Comment: @LGSon: Thanks for your comment, I already know that. But shouldn't the middle redirect domain should redirect to 3rd domain with it's own URLReferrer?